# android Disable native app for facebook login in sdk 3.18

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to get user authenticate with his Facebook. but the problem is arising if Facebook native app is installed in phone sdk 3.18 is using native app for SignIn.

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

      // callback when session changes state
      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
              mSession=session;
          // make request to the /me API
          Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {
                TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                Utility.setSharedPreference(MainActivity.this, ACCESS_TOKEN,
                                        mSession.getAccessToken());          
              }
            }
          }).executeAsync();
        }
      }
    });
```

I am using this code for Facebook LogIn